# Why is IObjectMapper not initialised when unit testing a controller method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, aspnetboilerplate, property-injection

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate template for ASP.NET Core. I have some application services which I have successfully unit tested.

I now want to test a controller method which uses these application services.
The controller method includes mapping operation like this:

```
var client = ObjectMapper.Map<ClientModel>(clientResponse.ClientSummary);
```

On executing this method, the test fails with an exception:

> Message: Abp.AbpException : Abp.ObjectMapping.IObjectMapper should be implemented in order to map objects.

Interestingly, the stack trace begins with `NullObjectMapper.Map`.

I am using the same initialisation for `AbpAutoMapper` in the unit test module as is used in the `Web.Mvc` module:

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfiles(typeof(PortalTestModule).GetAssembly());
});
```

However, when executing in the context of the MVC application, the mapping operations don't cause the exception.

What is it that I am failing to initialise in the `Test` project in relation to AutoMapper?

---

I have created a repro project. See [link](https://github.com/muiscatron/module-zero-core-template). There is a test called `GetFoos_Test` that tests the controller method `Index()` on `FoosController`.

```cs
public async Task GetFoos_Test()
{
    var mockFooService = new Mock<IFooAppService>();
    // ...

    var fooController = new FooController(mockFooService.Object);

    var result = await fooController.Index();

    result.ShouldNotBeNull();
}
```

As per @aaron's answer, property injecting IObjectMapper on the controller does solve the original error. However, it doesn't use the mappings that are part of what I am trying to test. I have created mappings in the Initialize method of the MVC module like this:

```
public override void Initialize()
{
IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(MyMvcModule).GetAssembly());

            Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(
               // Scan the assembly for classes which inherit from AutoMapper.Profile
               cfg =>
               {
                   cfg.AddProfiles(typeof(MyMvcModule).GetAssembly());

                   cfg.CreateMap<MyDto, MyModel>()
                       .ForMember(dest => dest.ReportTypeName, src => src.MapFrom(x => x.ReportType.Name));
...
```

Answer (score 1):

## 1. `NullObjectMapper` in `new` instances

`IObjectMapper` is property-injected into an instance (e.g. controller) when the instance is injected.

Since you cannot inject a controller in a unit test, you have to set `ObjectMapper` directly.

```cs
// using Abp.ObjectMapping;

var fooController = new FooController(mockFooService.Object);
fooController.ObjectMapper = LocalIocManager.Resolve<IObjectMapper>(); // Add this line
```

## 2. `NullObjectMapper` in injected instances

Add `[DependsOn(typeof(AbpAutoMapperModule))]` to your test module.

```cs
[DependsOn(typeof(AbpAutoMapperModule))]
public class MyTestModule : AbpModule
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).

Comment: I have created a repro project. See [link](https://github.com/muiscatron/module-zero-core-template). There is a test called GetFoos_Test which tests the controller method Index() on FoosController. The controller method is wired up so that it works in the UI.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at this project?

Comment: Apologies for the long delay. The original problem is resolved, i.e. IObjectMapper is now available. However, part of what I was trying to test was the object mappings  in my MVC project. I had defined these in the Initialize method of the MVC application module, but when the tests execute, they are using an "empty" object mapper. See edited question